# Client ID must be set as api.adwords.clientId in ads.properties. AdWords on GAE

Tags: java, maven, google-app-engine, google-ads-api, gcloud

I have a Java program that makes reports from Google AdWords, the authentications are working correctly since I have no issues issuing my reports with the Java API, but now when I run my Java API on the localhost with mvn appengine:devserver, it gives me this exception:

```
Client ID must be set as api.adwords.clientId in ads.properties.
If you do not have a client ID or secret, please create one in the API console: https://console.developers.google.com/project caused by: [clientId]
```

Only thing I change from the Java app to the GAE app is the doGet method, I comment it out and change my run() that is called by the doGet to main(String args[]).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, here's how:

This issue is due to the path of properties file.

First when deploying app, I was using a server so it doesn't read the properties file from the same directory as when it's run (ran?) on eclipse with the play button or with javac your_java_app.java

I moved my ads.properties from resources to src/main/webapp/WEB-INF and changed the OAuth2Credential from 
`..fromFile()..` to 
`..fromFile("WEB-INF/ads.properties")..`